# Ionic ui-router onEnter check throw errors at 2nd time around

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

So I have this very strange error: I want to check if a user is login when enter a state and redirect them back to SignIn page if they are not. So in my config I have:

```
.state('home', {
  cache: false,
    abstract: true,
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
  onEnter: function($state, MyFirebaseService) {
    // check session
    var userId = MyFirebaseService.LoginUserId();
    if (!userId) {
      $state.go('auth.signin')
    };
  }
})
```

So I type in http://localhost:8100/#/home/courses to go into courses page without login, everything work perfectly. User got redirect back to auth.signin view. But when I type in the address bar again http://localhost:8100/#/home/courses, it throw 4 errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '@' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth-signin@auth' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth-signup@auth' of null
```

My signin and signup are in an abstract view call auth. Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: wrap the $state.go in a $timeout

Comment: Thanks @chris T! Wrapped $state.go in $timeout won't solve the issue since this will just push the $state.go all the way to the end of the stack. This is the same as doing it inside the controller. Some function inside the controller are runned and throw error since use is not actually login...

Comment: Ahh. You can throw an error to stop the transition, or use events as an answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly perform those actions of authenticatio ncontrol on .run( with event catcher :

```
  .run([
          '$rootScope','authService','$q',
          function($rootScope, authService,q) {

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

// YOUR CONTROL & REDIRECT
        });
}]);
```

If you add some authorisation role control for instance on ui-router, for instance:

```
.state('home', {
                  url: "/home",
                  templateUrl: "includes/pages/homePage.html",
                  resolve : {
                    authorizedRoles :  function(){ return [ USER_ROLES['su'],
                               USER_ROLES['user'],
                               USER_ROLES['admin'],
                               USER_ROLES['skyadmin'],
                               USER_ROLES['skyuser'],
                               USER_ROLES['skysu']
                               ] } 

                  }

                })
```

You can easily check into `$stateChangeStart` with var `authorizedRoles = next.resolve.authorizedRoles();` and compare them with your user roles